# How to Wait for search data to load in table if the table rows disappears with search query ? Selenium c#

Tags: c#, jquery, selenium, webdriverwait, webautomation

The table loads data when first opened i created a method that takes random data and search for it, It takes time to clear the old data then display "No result" then load the new search result, the first row of the table always visible cause it displays "No Result" for a while Then All rows displayed once data loaded, How can i perform a wait that waits for data to clear then wait for new data to load 
I tried to use below code but keeps waiting even after all elements loaded

```
public void waitForSearchResult()
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
    try
    {
        wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//manual-map-bddl-list//tbody/tr"))));
    }
    catch (Exception )
    {

    }
```

[image]

[image: No Result Html]

Comment: Can you post the HTML code please? It is difficult to read the code from a screenshot. It looks like your XPath is searching for a `<manual-map-bddl-list>` tag, but that is not a valid HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the wait like this one:

```
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//manual-map-bddl-list//tbody/tr[2]")));
```

So hence you always have one row in your table that represents table caption you are better to wait for some other rows. My assumption is that if your table will load the second row it would mean that all the data is rendered.

This approach also ignores table header (considering the second `tr` as the first data row) row so that the condition wouldn't be met with empty results.

Comment: but i could get only 1 record of data in the first row, hence the case will fail though i got data. i

Comment: I do not understand you. If you get even one record it will mean that the search finished and you have some result. This would be sort of flag informing you that you can proceed with parsing the table. This woul likely work for the cases where the amount of data is reasonably small. Of course if you load 10mb of data to your table then probably not all the records would load completely by the time the first one has been shown.

Comment: R am checking if am getting matching results for the query hence it could be 1 or more rows and i have always 1 row displayed with "No Result" text till data load and replace this text, so if i use the wait on the 1st row its always there and if i use it with the 2nd row then it will fail if i got only 1 matching result

Comment: Can you share the html of the table when there is "no result"?

Comment: R, I have attached html for the "No result" table